# Losing two-way binding when pushing to array inside form (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm building a basic CRUD app with Angular 2. One of the form fields is an array of ingredients. I have an `addIngredient` method which pushes a new `Ingredient` to my `ingredients` array. As soon as I click the button which triggers this method the two-way binding appears to be lost.
When looking at the diagnostic data everything appears correct, but the data is lost from the form UI (see gif below):

[image]

relevant HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let ingredient of newRecipe.ingredients; let i = index; let f = first; let l = last">
  <md-input type="text" id="ingredientName" name="ingredientName" [(ngModel)]="ingredient.name" placeholder="ingredient" required></md-input>
  <md-input type="text" id="ingredientAmount" name="ingredientAmount" [(ngModel)]="ingredient.amount" placeholder="amount" required></md-input>
  <select id="ingredientMeasurement" name="ingredientMeasurement" [(ngModel)]="ingredient.measurement" required>
    <option *ngFor="let measurement of measurements" [value]="measurement">{{measurement}}</option>
  </select>
  <button md-icon-button color="primary" *ngIf="l" (click)="addIngredient()">
    <md-icon>add</md-icon>
  </button>
  <button md-icon-button color="warn" *ngIf="!f" (click)="removeIngredient(i)">
    <md-icon>remove</md-icon>
  </button>
</div>
```

relevant code from class:

```
addIngredient() {
  this.newRecipe.ingredients.push(new Ingredient());
}
```

NOTE: The `div` referenced above appears inside a `form` element. When I move this `div` outside the `form` everything works as expected.

Comment: What behavior are you expecting from pushing a new ingredient? That it is pushed onto the array with the ingredient name and ingredient amount? Definitionally a newed up object the way you're doing it only has the default values.

Comment: @silentsod, I'm pushing a new empty object, so I expect that second row to be empty. What surprised me is that the first row is now also empty even though the diagnostic logging at the top of the screen shows that `newRecipe.ingredients[0]` has data.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I can't see the screencap.

Comment: That's weird - your reasoning seems to be fine. I've tried to recreate it, and it does work for me: https://plnkr.co/edit/tQKUCK3rGqFupcJmgfdT?p=preview There must be something stupid going on we can't see ;)

Comment: @TomekSułkowski, Thanks for putting me on the right track. I'm still not sure what's up but I now know it has to do with forms. When I move the div shown in my question outside the `form` element it works as expected.

Comment: oooh, I didn't know about the form. Well, in that case I will have the answer for you in a moment :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What is happening here is that the `<form>` is using input's `name` properties to synchronise the models' values. In this case it's basically overriding the [ngModel] synchronisation.

What you can do to fix this is make `name`s dynamic:

```
<div *ngFor="let ingredient of newRecipe.ingredients; let i = index;">
   <md-input type="text" name="ingredientName_{{i}}"   
    [(ngModel)]="ingredient.name" placeholder="ingredient" required>
   </md-input>
</div>
```

(i.e. **`name="ingredientName_{{i}}"`**)

You can read more about this in the docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html

> When using the ngModel within  tags, you'll also need to supply a name attribute so that the control can be registered with the parent form under that name.
>
> It's worth noting that in the context of a parent form, you often can skip one-way or two-way binding because the parent form will sync the value for you.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Do you have a link to documentation for this `ingredientName_{{i}}` syntax? I want to make sure I understand what's happening here.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you. I was confused for a whole day. Bravo.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I have an array, with an ngFor on the HTML. I had [name]="something" and no errors, but binding was lost. I removed square brackets to name="something" and got an error asking me to name or standalone. Thank you!